# Windows XP text-mode installer, is it really a DOS application?

Tags: api, installation, windows-xp

When first installing Windows XP. I am presented with a textual interface.

What API does this textual installer use?

- 16-bit DOS application
- 32-bit DOS application
- Windows Native API
- Standard Win32 API

Comment: not sure how this counts as a practical programming question, unless you are planning to hack windows.

Comment: What is Windows _native_ API?

Comment: Hmm. The Standard Win32 API is the same thing as the "Windows Native API". And DOS is not a 32-bit operating system, so it's impossible that something could be a 32-bit DOS application. It's actually just a 32-bit Windows NT application. Just because something is in text mode doesn't make it MS-DOS.

Comment: This is 'on the fence' enough that I'm counting it as on topic. @Cody , probably should have made that an answer.

Comment: @Cody Gary The Win32 API is not *Native Mode* API, which is an undocumented API of Windows which exists early on in the boot process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going thorough a disassembler I have found the following...

This applies to a Windows XP Service Pack 2 installer...

**I386\SETUPLDR.BIN**

- The very beginning of text-mode setup where it asks for and loads basic drivers.
- It also asks about the recovery console.
- This is bootloader style code. Not a PE executable. I am unsure if it is 16-bit or 32-bit code.
- Uses ASCII strings.
- It actually takes about a minute to run, loading all the CD drivers and such.
- I am unsure if the Windows Kernel is running at this point.

**I386\USETUP.EXE**

- Windows kernel is definately running at this point.
- Displays the License agreement, the partitioner, and copies files to disk.
- 32-bit native mode PE executable. Native mode means unmanaged (i.e. not a .NET executable), BUT it also means that the executable ONLY uses the Native *undocumented* ntdll.dll API.
- This executable is Unicode aware and uses Unicode strings.